# Angularjs service not defined

Tags: angularjs

Trying to run a service with my controller.

```
    controllers.controller('test', function($scope, MathService) {
    $scope.test = Mathservice.add();
  });

controllers.service('MathService', function(){
 this.add = function() {
 var a = 1;
 var b = 2;
 var c = a + b;
 return c;
 };
});
```

The console says Mathservice not defined. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is called `MathService` not `Mathservice`, notice that javascript is case sensitive so then the word service on `MathService` must be capitalized like so:

```
$scope.test = MathService.add();
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with your Controller, you are refering the service as `Mathservice`, either change your service to **`Mathservice`** or Controller to **`MathService`**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('controllertest', ['$scope', 'Mathservice', function($scope, Mathservice) {
  $scope.test = Mathservice.add();
}]);
app.service('Mathservice', function() {
  this.add = function() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = a + b;
    return c;
  };
})
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SgA0ztPVPxTkA0wfS1HU?p=preview)**

Comment: not working, running the service from a separate document.